# AWS Resource explorer: Query with space symbol in tag value

Tags: aws-resource-explorer

I use Resource explorer to find resources with certain tags
Some values of tags have space symbol
I tried to run query `tag.key:application tag.value:"test\ 22"` but it doesn't work (no existing resources are shown)
Please advice me how to correctly address space character in the query
[image]